# Django , using UserModel to create custom message-inbox issue

Tags: django

I'm trying to create  a simple message-inbox app using the custom UserModel without using a plugin because it would allow me to freely customize it.

I created the model which is below and I figure out how to show the recipient the message but I can't figure out how to create a function that would show the replied message , the user sent .

For example , I sent you a message . You replied to the message , How can I show the replied message back including the original message and all the other message if the reply keep going.

This example display how I can read a single message sent by the user.

models

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    trash = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sentmessage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views

```
def Messages(request,id):
    user = User.objects.get(user=request.user)
    message = Message.objects.filter(pk=id,user=user)
    render (request,'message.html'{'message':message})
```

template

```
{{message.user}}
{{message.subject}}
{{message.body}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `ForeignKey` field to `'self'` on `Message` model can call it `in_response_to`. And, every time there is a response, create a new object, and assign the FK field to the message this reply was sent to. You would have to handle multiple responses to the same message gracefully.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    trash = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sentmessage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    in_response_to = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

You might also want to add the `created` and `updated` timestamps to keep track of the order of messages sent.

Also, please note you need a `related_name` on the FK on `User` or django would throw an error

Now, at the time of retrieval, get the fk objects till the point it is `None` or `blank`

In the simplest form, You can write a model method:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    #attributes here

    def get_all_in_reponse_to(self):
        obj = self.in_response_to
        response = ''
        while obj:
            response += obj.body
            obj = obj.in_response_to
        return response.
```

A more simpler approach would be (like what you were suggesting):

```
class Message(models.Model):
    #attributes here

    def get_all_in_reponse_to(self):
        response_objects = self.in_response_to.message_set.order_by('-created')
        for obj in response_object:
            response += obj.body
        return response.
```

I shall let you figure out the formatting, etc which is quite simple

Comment: karthikr , can you create a function so I can better understand how to  use in_response_to please karthikr

Comment: You have a foreign key to the user, so it has to be to the user right?

Comment: I don't quite understand this part get the fk objects till the point it is None or blank . If its a replied message , blank is False . What happen if their more than 1 different replied message from the user

Comment: you will have to handle that in the code. Everytime there is a reply, you need to update the FK field to the object it was in response to

Comment: i'm back again sorry , i'm been programming in django for a few months . I understand your model method . its chain reaction . I tap you , you tap someone . The thing I don't get is , How do you identify which replied message belong with which other ? 1 tap 2 , 2 tap 3 , 3 tap 4

Comment: I edited my answer to address this - Every time a message is replied to, you need to assign the FK field yourself. Please read the edit

Comment: You can look into http://code.google.com/p/django-messages/ for ideas. I think the model architecture is not very robust, it can be improved (IMHO)

Comment: I get what u mean , You get the first object id , then for every message related , You find out their main object id ,

Comment: You would have to change the model method if you keep track of main message. I was thinking even simpler. Chain of responses

Comment: Yeah , I can only half understand what your method model does because i have only few months in experience . i though your chain response was you assign all the related messages , the original message pk id . I would love to understand ur chain of response but I just can't piece it together . that why I tried to explain the tapping example . I mean if we keep updating the message with the latest primary object id , how do we find all the rest . sorry

Comment: Actually, your approach is so much more simpler. I updated the answer.

Comment: karhikr their a problem doing my approach , can u please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292697/django-custom-inbox-issue

Comment: Looks like you deleted the post